# Matching number lists python in order

Tags: python

My problem is trying to make two lists equal to each other in the specific order

As an example `[1,3,5,7,4,3,2,5,7,10] == [1,3,5,7,4,3,2,5,7,10]`

I want to keep computing random lists of 10 numbers until both equal each other in the specific order.

The problem I have is how would I make it equal to each other in that specific order? I know I cant do hardcoded numbers since they can be any place any value.

I know the statement `i[] == j[]` is not correct that's where I want to equal both lists and not sure what to put

```
import random
hats = []
people = []
count = 0

while True:
    for i in range(11):
        hats.add(random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]))
    for j in range(11):
        people.add(random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]))
        if(i[] == j[]):
             stop == True
             break
        else:
             count+=1
print(f'Count is {count}')
```

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your question, can’t you compare sorted lists?

Comment: I am making two separate lists of 10 numbers and I want to keep making new lists until both equal each other @DavidKong

Comment: To compare lists just use `i == j`

Comment: @l.m I just tried my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58194993/3091398) and i got count as `195784`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the job, but you may sit for a long time:

```
import random
hats = []
people = []
count = 0
while len(hats) != 10:
  k=0
  while k != 10:
      n = random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
      m = random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
      if(n == m):
        hats.append(n)
        people.append(m)
        k += 1
      else:
        hats   = []
        people = []
        count += 1
        k=10
print(count, hats, people)
```

I'm not sure if you have to reset the list if they are diferents, another shorter way would be:

```
import random
hats = []
people = []
count = 0
while len(hats) != 10:
  k=0
  while k != 10:
      n = random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
      m = random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
      if(n == m):
        hats.append(n)
        people.append(m)
        k += 1
      else:
        count += 1
        k=10

print(f"times: {count}", f"hats: {hats}", f"people: {people}")
```

outPut example:

```
times: 130 hats: [7, 7, 9, 5, 1, 5, 1, 7, 4, 8] people: [7, 7, 9, 5, 1, 5, 1, 7, 4, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I doubt this program will ever stop or if it even deterministic,but here it is.

```
import random

count = 0

while True:
    hats = []
    people = []
    for i in range(11):
        hats.append(random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]))
    for j in range(11):
        people.append(random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]))
    print(hats,people)
    if(hats == people):
        break
    else:
        count+=1
print(f'Count is {count}')
```

OUTPUT

```
[1, 4, 6, 2, 10, 2, 10, 2, 6, 3, 7] [2, 8, 9, 9, 4, 9, 9, 1, 2, 9, 9]
[10, 7, 10, 10, 4, 3, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4] [8, 4, 6, 8, 4, 9, 3, 4, 10, 3, 4]
[9, 9, 1, 9, 7, 2, 6, 3, 4, 9, 3] [1, 7, 2, 8, 9, 6, 4, 1, 1, 9, 4]
[7, 8, 1, 7, 1, 1, 1, 6, 8, 10, 9] [2, 9, 1, 1, 8, 5, 7, 2, 5, 7, 1]
[5, 5, 3, 1, 10, 4, 10, 2, 7, 10, 10] [3, 1, 3, 7, 3, 1, 5, 7, 5, 1, 10]
......
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) instead of [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) here.

*Repeatable random list*

```
import random 

list_size = 11 # length of the list 

hosts = [random.choice([i for i in range(1,11)]) for x in range(list_size-1)]
people = [random.choice([i for i in range(1,11)]) for x in range(list_size-1)]

count = 0

while True:
  random.shuffle(hosts) # shuffles the hosts list
  random.shuffle(people) # shuffles the people list
  print(hosts, people)
  count += 1
  if hosts == people:
    break

print(f'Count is {count}')
```

See this in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/BelatedImpracticalGraphs).

*Repeatable random list [Optimized]*

```
import random 

list_size = 10 # length of the list 

hosts = []
people = []

count = 0
while len(hosts) <= list_size:
  h = random.choice([i for i in range(1,11)])
  p = random.choice([i for i in range(1,11)])
  if h == p:
    hosts.append(h)
    people.append(p)
    print(hosts, people)
  else:
    hosts = []
    people = []
    count += 1

print(f'Count is {count}')
```

See it in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/HeartyOptimalBackticks)

*Non repeatable random list*

```
import random 

hosts = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] 
people = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

count = 0

while True:
  random.shuffle(hosts) # shuffles the hosts list
  random.shuffle(people) # shuffles the people list
  print(hosts, people)
  count += 1
  if hosts == people: # compares the list
    break

print(f'Count is {count}')
```

See this in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/GoldenDesertedPackage)

> I tried this on [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/GoldenDesertedPackage) and got ***195784***

Comment: `shuffle` won't work because the numbers can repeat themselves within each list, per OP's example.

Comment: @blhsing Thanks for pointing out. I didn't quite notice that detail.